# Summing over functions between lists

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

Working in Python.

Take k and n positive integers.

I have a function F with input a list L of positive integers where len(L) = k, max(L) < n+1. F returns an integer.

I want to return sum([F(L) for L a list of positive integers with len(L) = k, max(L)<n+1])

The naive approach is to have k nested for loops.

```
value = 0
for jj1 in range(1,n+1):
   for jj2 in range(1,n+1): 
     ...
        for jjk in range(1,n+1)
           value = value + F([jj1,jj2,...,jjk])
return value
```

This is not satisfactory because I want to take this sum in a loop over various values of k (so sometimes k =1, sometimes k=10).

I'm hoping there is some standard trick to do this?

Comment: Add a few examples as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> n, k = 4, 3
>>> list(product(range(1, n+1), repeat=k))
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 4), (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 1), (1, 3, 2), (1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 1), (1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 3), (1, 4, 4), (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 2, 4), (2, 3, 1), (2, 3, 2), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 1), (2, 4, 2), (2, 4, 3), (2, 4, 4), (3, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 1, 3), (3, 1, 4), (3, 2, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 2, 3), (3, 2, 4), (3, 3, 1), (3, 3, 2), (3, 3, 3), (3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1), (3, 4, 2), (3, 4, 3), (3, 4, 4), (4, 1, 1), (4, 1, 2), (4, 1, 3), (4, 1, 4), (4, 2, 1), (4, 2, 2), (4, 2, 3), (4, 2, 4), (4, 3, 1), (4, 3, 2), (4, 3, 3), (4, 3, 4), (4, 4, 1), (4, 4, 2), (4, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4)]
```

Given `F`, `n`, and `k`, you can therefore do:

```
sum(F(list(L)) for L in product(range(1, n+1), repeat=k))
```

(or leave off the `list` call if it's fine for `L` to be a tuple instead of a list)

Comment: And if you don't want different permutations of the same numbers, see `itertools.combinations`.  :)